# Java spring: Return a response to a request if takes longer then a specified time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request, timeout

Does spring have any solution to return a controller method early if a request takes too long?

The idea is too pass in a timeout value in the http header, and return a response if it takes more than that value.

Example controller method below i want to apply this to.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String test(@RequestHeader Long timeOut) {
    //process request here and return an error response if it goes longer than timeOut
    return "<Result of process request>";

  }
```

I could probably do this by messing around with threads, but would rather see if spring had some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type of the method to `Callable<String>`. This will make the controller method to execute asynchronously. Now, to set the timeout for handling the request you can update the spring mvc configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:async-support default-timeout="3000"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Or, you can set the timeout values on `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.